By plotting a pandas dataframe to a matplotlib table, how do I add images to each column
I am creating a discord bot that pulls football-related data from a football API using Python to get data of the league, and it would organize that data in a table format to display the rankings in an image of a table. The table also includes images of team emblem.
First I use create a pandas dataframe and store all the data retrived from the API in their. Then I use matplotlib library to convert them into a table.
The data includes position_data, team_name, point and a url of team crest (cresturl), I can plot the first 3 columns but plotting the images is where I need help. I can either plot the images into the dataframe first then convert them into a matplotlib table, or I can add them to an empty column after I convert the dataframe to a matplotlib table. Problem is I don't know how to do both.
Then I convert them into a png file, but since I don't want the png file to be stored in my harddrive, I'm storing them as BytesIO image variable
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #I'm gonna leave the part where I verify if the user message is a valid code
    table_image = get_table(code)
    await.message.channel.send(table_image)

def get_table(code):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Position', 'Team', 'Points', 'emblem'])
    url = ~~~{code}~~~
    conn = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    data = conn.json()
 
    images = []
    #data includes position_data, team_name, point and a url of team crest (cresturl)
    for each_team in data:
            new_row = {'Position': (position_data), 'Team':(team_name)],'Points':(points)}
            images.append(crestUrl)
            df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
    
    #converts it into a matplotlib table object
    table = render_table(df, images,header_column = 0, col_width = 2.0)
    # saved as BytesIO image variable so they are not saved as png files in my hard drive
    table_image = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(table_image, format='png')
    return table_image

def render_table(data, images, ~~~~~~)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
    ax.axis('off')
    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)


In the end I want the table to look something like 
y case.

put it into the column as html, then conver your table to render it. Read here

How do I return it as a table object?

I think you are over complicating it by making the table with matplot. Render the table as html is more straight forward and will allow you to embed images. Otherwise, to do it with matplot, you'll need to to read in the image and superimpose it into a cell, and make sure it right size, etc.

By the way, is there a way to remove the default index column for data frame object?

Is there a way to convert the html file to pdf file without saving it as html file on the hard drive first? Because I don't know how to use BytesIO library to temporarily save the html file

what do you mean temporarily save it? You could convert it to an image perhaps.

try something like this: Youll need to pip install imgkit
import imgkit

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #I'm gonna leave the part where I verify if the user message is a valid code
    table_image = get_table(code)
    await.message.channel.send(table_image)
    
# convert your links to html tags 
def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'

def get_table(code):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Position', 'Team', 'Points', 'emblem'])
    url = ~~~{code}~~~
    conn = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    data = conn.json()
 
    #data includes position_data, team_name, point and a url of team crest (cresturl)
    for each_team in data:
        imgUrl = path_to_html(crestUrl)
        new_row = {'Position': (position_data), 'Team':(team_name),'Points':(points), 'emblem': imgUrl}
        df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
    
    html_data = df.to_html(escape=False, formatters=format_dict, index=False)

    # saved as BytesIO image variable so they are not saved as png files in my hard drive
    
    # Convert HTML to PNG image
    imgkit.from_string(html_data, 'out.png')  # Saves directly to a file named 'out.png'

    # If you want to keep it in memory instead of saving to disk:
    img = BytesIO()
    imgkit.from_string(html_data, img)
    
    return img


For get_table() function, it returns a html object. in async def on_message(message), once I get the html object I want to convert it to a png file and send it in the message channel, the problem is I don't want to save it in the disk. I know how to use the BytesIO library to convert jpg to png without saving on the disk but I don't know how to implement it when it's converting from html to image

ah ok. I think I get it. I'll have to take a look tomorrow, and I'l update the code above for you to try

whats confusing though is in your code, you're saving the file plt.savefig(table_image, format='png')

Hm it still doesn't work because imgkit.from_string doesn't accept BytesIO file in the parameters. I'll try something else I appreciate the help
